# Direct use of Sentinel 2 L2A imagery for vegetation analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, ndvi, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction

I am working on my research to calculate the green vegetation in the study area using sentinel 2 L2A 10m resolution. Do I need to perform any correction or smoothing before analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentinel 2 L2A is ready for further processing, no more corrections needed.

Also have a look at the [SCL band](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/algorithm-overview#:%7E:text=Classification%20Mask%20Generation), it contains a pre-calculatated classification with classes like different types of clouds and cloud shadow, but also vegetation, water,...

Comment: Thankyou @Pieter. I will check out.